# Set up system of linear equations and solve

Tags: equation, solver, simplify

i need to set up a system of linear equations and solve it.
The calculations are based on a graph and are always of the same format.
I need ideas how to solve my problem efficiently...

At first I create all necessary equations. Here is an example:

```
q = 4,9 + r
r = 2,3 + 0,03q + 0,11d + 0,85(1 + r)
d = 15,3 + 0,02q + 0,74r
```

This step is already done. My program creates this formulas. My problem is now, what is the most efficient way to calculate the values?
I need to prepare the equations to be able to use them in a matrix solver. Hence, i have to eliminate the brackets and combine the values...

I thought of combining multiple java libraries to reach the goal. At first I wanted to use a simplifier to simplify all equations and finally a matrix solver to calculate the values. Here are my thoughts:

Step 1: Eliminate brackets if necessary)

```
q = 4,9 + r
r = 2,3 + 0,03q + 0,11d + 0,85 + 0.85r
d = 15,3 + 0,02q + 0,74r
```

Step 2: Combine values)

```
q = 4,9 + r
r = 3,15 + 0,03q + 0,11d + 0.85r
d = 15,3 + 0,02q + 0,74r
```

Step 3: Prepare matrix)

```
-4,9 = -q + r
-3,15 = -r + 0,03q + 0,11d + 0,85r
-15,3 = -d + 0,02q + 0,74r
```

Step 3.2: Combine values)

```
-4,9 = -q + r
-3,15 = -0,15r + 0,03q + 0,11d
-15,3 = -d + 0,02q + 0,74r
```

Step 3.3: Sort values)

```
-4,9 = -q + r
-3,15 = 0,03q - 0,15r + 0,11d
-15,3 = 0,02q + 0,74r -d
```

Step 3.4: Matrix structure)

```
-4,9 = -1 1 0
-3,15 = 0,03 -0,15 0,11
-15,3 = 0,02 0,74 -1
```

And now I can use a matrix solver like jama. There are several steps that have to be performed. But whats the most efficient way without reinventing the wheel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us your Java code.

Comment: Which code? I told you that im not sure how to proceed... There are a bunch of systems I need to solve. The formulas have already been created. Now I need to write an extra tool for my dissertation to solve the equation systems.

Comment: SO is not a service that will write code for you. Please start on your own. If you have problems, come back and ask a specific question.

Comment: Please read my post. I dont want any code from you at all. I want ideas and suggestions how to implement an efficient solution. There is e.g. xjep that can simplify my equations. Then, I need to set up the matrix and calculate it. I just wanted to know whether there is a more simple and efficient solution.

Comment: it looks like gauss elemination , http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/95linear/GaussianElimination.java.html you might check that.

Comment: Right,  İlker. All these libraries and procedures require a matrix. And I need to set up this matrix now. But at first I need to set up the equations and then I can create the matrix structure..